# IOS/Objective-C/Autolayout: Swipe gesture on view only working once and then view moves with swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to debug a weird issue.  I have code that creates a leftswiperecognizer, assigns it to the view and has a handler that changes certain elements on swipe.

I have versions of this code working fine.  On one VC, however, after the first swipe which also works fine, on the second swipe, instead of the gesture getting recognized, the entire view moves--as though you are dragging it or attempting to scroll it horizontally.  There is a scroll recognizer present, but normally it only responds to vertical drags.  There is also a tap recognizer on this screen. They both work fine.  The same app has other screens with leftswipe, scroll and tap recognizers all playing fine.

In short, works fine first swipe.  Then no swipe recognized.  Has anyone encountered this issue previously?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
//create recognizer (called from viewdidload)
-(void) addLeftSwipeRecognizer {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSwipe:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

- (void) handleLeftSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    self.title = @"New title";
//some other changes to labels.
}    

//other recognizers
called from viewdidload    
-(void) addListTapRecognizer {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapList = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(handleTap:)];
      tapList.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    self.listSub.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    self.listSub.editable=NO;
    [self.listSub addGestureRecognizer:tapList];
}
- (void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    UITextView *textView =  (UITextView *)recognizer.view;
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:textView];

    CGPoint position = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);
     UITextPosition *tapPosition = [textView closestPositionToPoint:position];
//do some stuff based on position of tap
}
//called from viewdidload
-(void) addScrollGestureRecognizer {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapScroll = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(tapped)];
    tapScroll.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapScroll];
}
//dismiss keyboard when you tap scrollview
- (void) tapped
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: "On one VC, however, after the first swipe which also works fine, on the second swipe, instead of the gesture getting recognized, the entire view moves" So the obvious question is: what's special about that one VC? For example, is it in a page view controller? In a navigation controller? It must be in _some_ environment that is special and different from the others.

Comment: It is largely similar, a Detail VC for a tableVC.  The handletap recognizer is more complicated than other tap recognizers.  However when you drag the view, none of the gesture recognizers fire.  Something else is happening.

Answer (score 1):

> on the second swipe, instead of the gesture getting recognized, the entire view moves

Let's assume, for the sake of discussion, that you are doing everything correctly and not adding your swipe gesture recognizer to the wrong view. Well, then, the implication is that the "entire view" has a gesture recognizer, either a swipe or a pan gesture recognizer probably, and it is recognizing first and causing your gesture recognizer to fail.

You can readily find that out by asking for that view's `gestureRecognizers`. Here is a utility method that lets you ask a view for all its gesture recognizers and all the gesture recognizers of its superviews, because they can affect this view:

```
extension UIView {
    func reportAllGestureRecognizers() {
        if let grs = self.gestureRecognizers {
            print(grs)
        }
        if let sup = self.superview {
            sup.reportAllGestureRecognizers()
        }
    }
}
```

At some point after your view is in the interface (i.e. after `viewDidAppear`), send that message to some view, e.g. `self.view.reportAllGestureRecognizers`. You may be surprised at what you learn.

If that turns out to be the case, there are delegate methods and other devices that allow you to mediate between your gesture recognizer and the other one, so that yours recognizes first.

Comment: Thanks, it is going to take me a bit to translate swift into obj-c but I will try this out.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice this was Objective-C. But you get the idea: it's a category on UIView with an instance method that NSLogs `[self gestureRecognizers]` and then calls the same method on `[self superview]`. In Objective-C that will fail harmlessly if the superview is `nil` and so the recursion will end.